# C2DM Auth Error

Tags: android, android-c2dm, auth-token

I have an `C2DM` based application, which works fine, but recently I am getting `Auth Error`
 although I am getting the RID(Registration ID) and the message is being sent.
 Recently I read that  Client Login keys are about to expire (Apr 30th), `may be` because of that I am getting this Error.
 My question is that how do I Regenerate the `Client Login Keys` ????
 How do I regenerate the `AUTH TOKEN`?????
 Any help would be thankful.... 
 Thanks

Comment: seems like no body knows the Answer here too !!! Waiting for answers Thank You !!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find your answer here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-c2dm-client-login-key.html

Please mind that:

- you need to watch your communication for Update-Client-Auth headers and update the token accordingly
- ClientLogin protocol is deprecated right now (still the only one that is working - people are reporting lots of problems for OAuth 2.0)
- Once in a while you might fall into a problem that the solution provided will require captchas and you will have to do it manually in browser (a really stupid solution for a service-to-service solution).

They say that once you send at least one message a week and watch out for Update-Client-Auth header you'll never have to regenerate your Auth again.